# Angle Bisector Question

Tags: geometry

Please Help Me With This Question:

$\overline{BE}$ and $\overline{CF}$ are angle bisectors of $\triangle ABC$ that meet at $I$ as shown below, and we have $CE = 4$, $AE = 6$, and $AB = 8$. Find $BF$.

Diagram: http://s32.postimg.org/w2px2v4g5/Wk7.png

I got the answer $\dfrac{16}{5}$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5):

According to angle bisector theorem, $\frac{|CE|}{|EA|}=\frac{|BC|}{|BA|}$ and $\frac{|AF|}{|FB|}=\frac{|AC|}{|CB|}$.

From $\frac{|CE|}{|EA|}=\frac{|BC|}{|BA|}$, we have $\frac{4}{6}=\frac{|BC|}{8}$, so $|BC|=\frac{16}{3}$

From $\frac{|AF|}{|FB|}=\frac{|AC|}{|CB|}$, we have $\frac{8-|BF|}{|BF|}=\frac{10}{\frac{16}{3}} \Rightarrow \frac{8-|BF|}{|BF|}=\frac{15}{8}$. Then cross multiply. We get $64-8|BF|=15|BF|$, so $|BF|=\frac{64}{23}$.

Comment: Thanks! I got $|BC|=\frac{16}{3}$ also, but couldn't get $|BF|$

Answer (score 0):

In the figure below there is the red angle bisector $AG$. The Ceva's theorem gives

$$6nx=4m(8-x)$$ and the theorem of the angle bisector $AG$ gives $$8n=10m$$ It follows $$\frac{6x}{8}=\frac{4(8-x)}{10}\Rightarrow \color{red}{x=\frac{64}{23}}$$

[image]